# jQuery / JavaScript incrementing value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make multiple divs appear in a defined time and when I click it, gives 300 Points (value), it starts with a value of 0 (punctuation) and triggers a function when the page is ready

```js
var puntuacion = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  FadeDiv();

  function FadeDiv() {
    var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    $newdiv = $("<div id='circle-green'></div>").css({
      'left': posx + 'px',
      'top': posy + 'px'
    });
    $newdiv.appendTo('body').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
      FadeDiv();
    });
  }
  $("#Points").text(puntuacion);
  $("#circle-green").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    puntuacion+=300;
    $("#Points").text(puntuacion);
  });

  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 1000);
  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 500);
  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 100);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#circle-green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Points"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k6shp80d/

but I can just click the first div, why? maybe because I'm new on JavaScript and jQuery, ask me any question or any doubt you have!, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The points wouldn't go above 300. You have written `puntuacion = +300` instead of `puntuacion += 300`

Comment: You should make every `ID` on your html unique and I guess that's not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating many `#circle-green` `div`s that don't get removed, and you are calling `$("#circle-green").click`. Change the `#circle-green` to a `class`, not and `id`. Also, change the click handler and the CSS.

Fixed!

```js
   
$(document).ready(function() {
 var puntuacion = 0;
  FadeDiv();

  function FadeDiv() {
    var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    $newdiv = $("<div class='circle-green'></div>").css({
      'left': posx + 'px',
      'top': posy + 'px'
    }).click(function() {
  $(this).remove();
  puntuacion += 300;
  $("#Points").text(puntuacion);
 });
    $newdiv.appendTo('body').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
      FadeDiv();
    });
  }

  $("#Points").text(puntuacion);

  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 1000);
  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 500);
  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 100);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.circle-green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Points"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery onClick function and use Class instead of Id as below:

```
$(".circle-green").on('click',function(){

});
OR
$(document).on('click', '.circle-green', function () {
});
```

Hope that solves your query.
https://jsfiddle.net/k6shp80d/1/

Comment: Please don't ask the OP to mark your answer as "accepted answer" in your answer or ask for an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your error was in  `puntuacion =+ 300;`
The correct syntax is:

```
puntuacion += 300;
```

The final code should look like this:

```js
var puntuacion = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  FadeDiv();

  function FadeDiv() {
    var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
$newdiv = $("<div onclick='greenFunc(this);' id='circle-green'></div>").css({
  'left': posx + 'px',
  'top': posy + 'px'
});
    $newdiv.appendTo('body').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
      FadeDiv();
    });
  }
  $("#Points").text(puntuacion);

  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 1000);
  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 500);
  setTimeout(FadeDiv, 100);
});

function greenFunc(element){
    $(element).remove();
    puntuacion += 300;
    $("#Points").text(puntuacion);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#circle-green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Points"></div>
```

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/zGOZrV